# Flutter-based Workaround For Loopback Flow Error

Tags: flutter, google-api, google-oauth

I’m asking if somebody knows a Flutter-based workaround for the following error caused by Google’s decision to block the **loopback flow** when authenticating to **Google APIs** using the package **googlesapi_auth**:

[image]

Some context:

- My Flutter app uploads and downloads files to **Google Drive**.
    To do this, my app leverages 3 packages: **googlesapi**,
  **googlesapi_auth**, and **url_launcher** package.
- I am using the **clientViaUserConsent()** function from the
  **googlesapi_auth** package in order to obtain an **authenticated HTTP
  client** (and access tokens that I cache for next time I need to
  another instance of an HTTP client).
- It is the returned HTTP client above that I use to make upload and download file requests to/from Google Drive using the constructs implemented by the **googlesapi** package.
- During the clientViaUserConsent() call, I pass the necessary **OAuth client id** (from the Google Cloud Console) and the necessary Google Drive **scopes**.
- The way **clientViaUserConsent()** works is that I pass a callback
  function to its 3rd positional argument. This function is called when
  the user has to authenticate to Google’s authentication/authorization
  server by launching the url to the authorization form that is passed
  as an argument to the callback function. I launch the url using the
  **launchUrl()** function from the **url_launcher** package.
- If authentication succeeds, it is only then that **clientViaUserConsent()** completes with the needed instance to the authenticated HTTP client object.

ie-

```
var client = await clientViaUserConsent(
  clientId,
  scopes,
  (String urlConsentForm) async {
    await launchUrl(Uri.parse(urlConsentForm));
  },
);
```

This was all working pre-2022, but when I tried to use the same code last week, I got the loopback flow error above.

Reading the documentation to this error, it says the solution is to use the new **google_sign_in** package, but when I looked into this package, I don’t think it returns an authenticated HTTP client and I was hoping to find a solution that does so that I don’t have to deconstruct the rest of my code.

More specifically, I want to keep using the **Dart**-based constructs implemented by **googlesapi** instead the **REST**-based constructs published the Google API spec.

Any ideas? All help much appreciated.

/Jose

Comment: Guessing your using a installed app credentials?

Comment: @DaImTo, I don't know what 'installed app credentials' mean. 

In terms of credentials, what I have is my app's OAuth client ID which is obtained from the Google Cloud Console, and if I don't have any access tokens cached, I call clientViaUserConsent() which returns with URL to an authentication form which I launch, allowing me to authenticate using my Google UserID/Password.

If I do have access tokens cached, I call another API which returns the needed HTTP client a lot faster without needing for me to authenticate manually.

Is this what you mean by 'installed app credentials'?

Comment: do you have a credetinals.json file that you are loading your client id from?  is urlConsentForm a string you can show me?  If urlConsentForm has a client id in it which it should please remove that from the string redact it

Comment: @DalmTo, no that's cuz pre-2022, I didnt need the secrets part of the credentials.json. I was just manually passing the OAuth Client ID verbatim from the Google Cloud Console.

Comment: Okay then any idea where your code could be getting its redirect uri from then?  Or wait what library are you using for the auth is this one of the standard ones?

Comment: https://github.com/google/googleapis.dart/issues/452  <-- might this help

Comment: @DaImTo, thanks for your replies.

To your 1st question, the redirect is coming from the urlConsentForm string which is as follows, (clientID redacted):

"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx-i2p8763g6u7sthlbuk1huge7kqja0ah5.apps.googleusercontent.com&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A63577&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.file&code_challenge=z1YfOQcfPoZd8O8Ef4piF80ueI75f5_Im9KCVOgp79w&code_challenge_method=S256&state=lPjlouMnnICNCjLltkqvl30eGkkDcx0f"

Comment: @Dalmto, to your 2nd question, I am using googleapis_auth to authenticate to Google APIs. I shall try that other package you suggested shortly and Ill keep you posted. Thanks again.

Comment: I would definatly switch the package.  but your redirect uri should be http://127.0.0.1

Comment: @DaImTo, the path of the redirect url, the one that has the OAuth client ID as a parameter you mentioned, is pointing to accounts.google.com yada yada. Should I change it to 127.0.0.1?

You see, Im not really well versed with HTTP, just occasionally setting fields in the headers and doing basic POST and GET requests, so my definition of a redirect may not be correct. But I would LOVE to learn.

Comment: Check the answer i just posted its to long for a comment.

Comment: @Dalmto, just having cocoapods errors with google_sign_in. Will try your suggestion as soon as I resolve them.

Comment: I would help you test it if i could figure out how to get a flutter test environment running.  You have me curious

Comment: A bid of background info your issue is probably related to [making-oauth-flows-safer](https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/02/making-oauth-flows-safer.html) and you probably should read though this [oob-migration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/resources/oob-migration)

Comment: @DaImTo, Ive given up trying to solve my cocoapods errors with google_sign_in. Its seems that theres still a lot of compatibility problems with M1 based boxes. Will now move to an Android device just to try out your suggested solution. Stay tuned...

Comment: @DalmTo, got pulled away to another task. Now that I'm back, I'm now getting PlatformException() errors when calling GoogleSignIn.signIn(). Lots of occurrence of this symptom, but Im not using Firebase so all suggestions Ive read thus far is inapplicable. Will now be making a post. Stay tuned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the urlConsentForm you have shown me.  If you look at it you will find it contains the following `redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A63577`

This redirect uri is incorrect. it should be `http://127.0.0.1` not localhost some port.

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx-i2p8763g6u7sthlbuk1huge7kqja0ah5.apps.googleusercontent.com&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A63577&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.file&code_challenge=z1YfOQcfPoZd8O8Ef4piF80ueI75f5_Im9KCVOgp79w&code_challenge_method=S256&state=lPjlouMnnICNCjLltkqvl30eGkkDcx0f

That being said i still think that you should be using the package mentioned in this issue post [#452](https://github.com/google/googleapis.dart/issues/452)

Comment: @DalmTo, finally able to confirm your answer as working. Thank you.

It took awhile cuz google_sign_in kept giving me a PlatformException() while signingin. Turns out, I must not pass the OAuth client ID during the GoogleSignIn() object instantiation which is super weird cuz I wasnt passing it anywhere else except there. But I'll just leave it be until it barfs and then deal with it then.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the solution was to use the [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) package instead of `googlesapi_auth`, and instead of `AuthClient` you can use the flutter [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package for the api requests.
All you need to do is to follow these two steps.

step 1 -

```
GoogleSignInAccount? _currentUser;

GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  clientId: "THE CLIENT ID WHICH GOOGLE CONSENT SCREEN PROVIDED",
  scopes: <String>[
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
  ],
);

Future<void> _handleSignIn() async {
    try {
      await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    } catch (error) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(error);
      }
    }
  }

GoogleSignInAccount? _currentUser;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount? account) {
      setState(() {
        _currentUser = account;
      });
    });
    _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
  }
```

step 2 -

After signing in to your account you can use the `_currentUser!.authHeaders` as your header for each http request.